# how to mach_inject without sudo

Tags: macos, plugins, sudo, finder

I've written a plugin for finder on Mac(mountain lion) and it works perfectly, but I have to run the bundle with sudo. Then I make a package(Packagemaker) to run this bundle and it failed(install correctly and if I run it by clicking desktop icon it failed, if run though commandline with sudo, it works).
Does anybody know how to fix this issue just like installing dropbox (and then sync icon shows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that, internally, mach_inject calls the function task_for_pid.

This function returns the kernel task id for the given process pid and due to security reasons, Apple now requires that use of this function can only take place from users that are members of either the *root* or *procmod* groups. This explains why running sudo works for you.

If you're just developing this for just your own use, the simplest method is to add yourself to the procmod group. However, if you want to distribute the application, you'll need to ensure that any installer installs the program to run as a member of the root or procmod groups.

One possibility is to separate your application into two parts, where the second is registered to run with elevated privileges using [SMJobBless](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html). If you don't program in Objective-C, don't worry as the actually parts of SMJobBless that are required are just C function calls; look for *AuthorizationCopyRights* and *SMJobBless* in the [given example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SMJobBless/Listings/SMJobBlessApp_SMJobBlessAppController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010071-SMJobBlessApp_SMJobBlessAppController_m-DontLinkElementID_5).

Alternatively, if the application is code-signed, that should work too, though it's not something I've tried myself. You can [read about that here](http://os-tres.net/blog/2010/02/17/mac-os-x-and-task-for-pid-mach-call/).

---

As of OS X 10.11 (El Capitan), `task_for_pid` is an entitled function call, only available to software with a specific entitlement in its certificate and no longer available to 3rd party developers.

This breaks mach_inject, making it harder to retrieve another process's mach task, whilst SIP ([System Integrity Projection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)) is enabled.

Comment: I have checked dropbox, box and google drive, I found box is possibly using the the method you mentioned (separate into two parts) and I am trying this, but I'm still wondering how dropbox and google drive working around this? you can tell these two are also using mach_inject though code reverse engineering. But it seems that they don't use any elevated privilege skills?

Comment: I have verified the methods you mentioned(separate application into two parts). It works. thanks.